# An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application'] while integration Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to implement **JetPack Compose** using Canary 8 but getting this error every time I try to sync gradle

> **An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']**
>
> My app\build.gradle file is below

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.30'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha02'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

> My build.gradle file is below

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0-beta01'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha08'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> and this is my gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.2-all.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

Comment: Do you have the exception as well?

Comment: @Gaëtan yes, org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException:

Comment: use short key Ctr+Alt+Shift+S or Go to File > Project Structure and change JDK location to Embedded JDK

Comment: UPDATE 2023.11.22: If you download template from https://kmp.jetbrains.com/，and already using Java 11，try Java 17 direct.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Android Gradle Plugin 7 requires Java 11.

Go to `File` > `Project Structure` and change JDK location to `Embedded JDK`.

**UPDATE 2023.11.22:**
If you have downloaded template from https://kmp.jetbrains.com，and are already using Java 11，try Java 17 direct.

Comment: where is `Project Structure` ? i can not find it.

Comment: @a55 As the answer said, "File -> Project Structure...". Or, the shortcut: "CMD+;".

Comment: use short key Ctr+Alt+Shift+S

Answer (score 32):

For Android Studio Artic Fox (2020.3.1), you can find the JDK settings here:

```
Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK
```

Then change the setting to "Embedded JDK"

Comment: Nothing, still the same error

Comment: here is the answer I was looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 25):

For Android Studio Artic Fox (2020.3.1) Android Gradle Plugin 7 requires Java 11.
use short key **Ctr+Alt+Shift+S** or
Go to **File > Project Structure** and change JDK location to Embedded JDK. Same Answer @Mariusz
[image: Here is Screenshot]

Comment: I'm using Java 11 and still have this error

Answer (score 19):

Check the following picture to re-direct the JDK source:

Step 1.
[image]

Step 2.
[image]

Step 3.
[image]

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Was already 11 so nope, not a solution

Comment: Thank you! Now I can skip downloading JDK 17

Answer (score 5):

I have issue with build cache and the error:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > The option 'android.enableBuildCache' is deprecated.
     The current default is 'false'.
     It was removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
```

Removing `org.gradle.caching=true` from root gradle properties file solved the issue.

Comment: What could be the impact if I remove org.gradle.caching=true from the existing project

Comment: We don't need it anymore. You can remove this

Comment: In addition to this, I also had to make this change: `android.enableBuildCache=false` in the same file (`gradle.properties`)

Answer (score 3):

File -> Project Structure -> Module
[image]

Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deploment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

[image]

Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#versioning-update), AGP 7.x.x requires Gradle 7. As seen in you're gradle-wrapper, you're using Gradle 6.8.2. Try updating the project to use Gradle 7 (The current latest version is 7.0-milestone-2). You can do so manually or simply through File > Project Structure.

Comment: I dont understand why android behave so mistereously as same configuration was working fine 2 days back. Also when I am trying to update Gradle from 6.8.2 to 7.x.x , it starts giving another exception

Comment: Could you share the new exception with us?

Comment: you already use AGP 7 `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha08` Android Gradle Plugin != Gradle, I bet AGP in alpha08 got some bug or some other dependencies are bugged or not upteded

Comment: update: switched to gradle 7 m 2 `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-milestone-2-bin.zip` still giving same exception `An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']`

Comment: @Mariusz,  Hurraah!!! fixed this time. but it is very stange that I have developed a demo app with distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.2-bin-zip and java8. but suddenly it stopped working. Thank you so much.. Upgrading java 8 to java 11 solved my problem.

Comment: @Devraj most probably you used stable Android Studio (with java8) and AS Preview uses AGP 7 that require J11

Comment: @Mariusz but Android Jetpack compose does not work on Stable Android studio, It requires Canary. correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

changing the compile sdk version, source compatibility, and target compatibility from the Project structure.
[project structure(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aleN.png)
changing android gradle plugin version and gradle version from the Project structure.
[project structure(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwJgA.png)
changing gradle jdk from setting->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle.
[gradle jdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBe14.png)
add and changing.
[add and change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJmdk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is first go to the:

1. Android Studio menu -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment
2. In the gradle projects section, select: Gradle JDK version drop down menu
3. It will show all the JDKs you have installed on your device // See attached image bottom right drop down menu.
4. Select JDK 11.

Done, now you should be able to build without issues.

Or if you are using CLI to build, then change the ~/.zshrc ( or bash equivalent file for Ubuntu, I am using MacOS 11 so it is Zsh here, you should be having Bash on your device) to JDK11. After your change to the Zsh/Bash resource file, save it and then execute command:

- `$ source ~/.zshrc` // to update change
- `$ java -version` // to check java version

Sample output java version:

```
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.8.10.1 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.8.10.1 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Note:
*I am using MacOS 11.2.1, Android Studio Artic Fox, 2020.3.1, Gradle Version 7.0.2*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update your plugins to minimal 1.7.0

```
plugins {
   ...
   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}
```