# How to use lambda expression in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have tried everything I could find from `StackOverflow` to make this problem right but none of them succeeded.

The strange thing is : I can use lambda such as

```
 activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                });
```

and stream like this

```
activity.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0).stream().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

but this will fail :

```
activity.getPackageManager()
.getInstalledPackages(0)
.stream()
.filter(e -> e.packageName.contains("com"))
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

### my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mylearn.simplesender"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.9.2'
    implementation group: 'com.alibaba', name: 'fastjson', version: '1.2.78'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '31.0.1-android'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

and also, here is my Gradle setting in `Android Studio`

---

[image]

---

here is my compile setting in `Android Studio`

---

[image]

It shows an unreadable error, and when I debug this expression in the watcher shows :

```
Compilation failed:
-source 1.6 中不支持 lambda 表达式
  (请使用 -source 8 或更高版本以启用 lambda 表达式)
```

which means I'm using source version 1.6, and it does not support lambda expression and told me to use source 8 or higher to enable lambda expression.

But I'm already in java 11, how could this happen?

Comment: Your Gradle JDK is one thing.  It's not relevant here.  Your Gradle `sourceCompatibility` and  `targetCompatibility` settings are both "JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8".  That looks OK.  Your Android/Java source compiler is a different thing. Check "compiler" settings in Android Studio.

Comment: @paulsm4 My "complier" setting is added to the question description, it seems there is nothing I can change. Should I specify the command-line options?

Comment: I think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/68616770/15005298

Comment: @YaqoobBhatti nope, my gradle setting was the same as this before I got this problem, unfottunately I found that I can use lambda like ```threadpool.submit( ()->{......} )``` but I cannot use lambda in stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, I have the problem solved by change my build.gradle file according to the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#groovy).
now my build.gradle file is :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.infiai.simplesender"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.9.2'
    implementation group: 'com.alibaba', name: 'fastjson', version: '1.2.78'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '31.0.1-android'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

I can now using both stream and lambda together, but I didn't figure out how to use this in debug mode when the expression is in watches window, it will still throw exception even the same expression in my code was running succeed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to App level build.gradle>

then put this code in android {} block

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

after this your code look like this

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "in.chikuai.example"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

}
```

Comment: right, recently I found that I can use lambda expression such as ```threadpool.submit( ()->{.....} )```. it seems that lambda expression is already supported. But I cannot use the feature of using lambda in stream (it is also a java 8 feature I think, I can use stream alone, and also lambda alone, but when using both stream and lambda, it will crash).

Comment: I have no idea. It is a common usage when coding with spring boot, but in android, such as this expression, if I use lambda in stream, it will crash.```getPackageManager()
.getInstalledPackages(0)
.stream()
.filter(e -> e.packageName.contains("com"))
.collect(Collectors.toList())```