# Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8(react-native Android)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I upgraded my gradle version from 4.x to 7.x,

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2')
        ...
    }
}
```

and then started to face the issue below:

```
* Where:
Build file '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TradeApp/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/build.gradle' line: 72

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':@react-native-community_async-storage'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.library'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

I would appreciate if someone can help to resolve this issue and not a workaround(downgrading back to 4.x works, but I want to know why it's not working with 7.x)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68616770/15005298 i think this will solve your problem

Comment: This is already there, issue looks more like the package issue, and not my native android.

Answer (score 0):

you can change Java version here:

[image]