# gradle lombok plugin 8.0.1 UnknownConfigurationException

Tags: java, gradle, lombok

I'm trying to upgrade lombok from 6.6.3 to 8.0.1 but I'm getting errors at build time.

The exception is:

```
org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'java']
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.exceptionOccurred(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:207)
    [...]
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException

Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.UnknownConfigurationException: Configuration with name 'mainSourceElements' not found.
    at 
    [...]
    io.freefair.gradle.plugins.lombok.LombokPlugin.configureJavaPluginDefaults(LombokPlugin.java:71)
```

My build.gradle plugin section is like this:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "8.0.1"
    <other plugins>
    }
```

I can't find info online about this specific error so if anyone has an idea it would be really appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An exception occurred applying plugin request \[id: 'com.android.application'\] while integration Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66376361/an-exception-occurred-applying-plugin-request-id-com-android-application-wh)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are having issue with java plugin not the lombok. Try changing JDK to internal JDK in project structure (if you are using IntelliJ)

> Go to `File -> Project Structure` and change JDK location to `Embedded JDK`

or,

> `Preferences -> Build`, `Execution`, `Deployment -> Build Tools` -> `Gradle -> Gradle JDK`

Comment: Thank you, I don't have "embedded  jdk" in my IntelliJ, but I've tried changing the gradle JVM to "project SDK" and it didn't make a difference. 
This problem is not there with the previous lombok version... I'm using Java 11 for this project BTW.

Comment: Did you try upgrading the Java version as well?