# Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

Full Error --

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11.
> Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Just Created the new project and getting this error

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-studio-error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-cur) help you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Step 1: Just Download the Java 17. [LINK](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-windows)

Step 2: Set environment variable for Java 17.

Step 3: In Android Studio Go to File → settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle → Gradle JDK And Select Java 17.

Step 4: Delete the Gradle Cache directory if you still get the error, on Mac it's located at `~/.gradle/caches`

BUILD SUCCESSFUL :)

Comment: Note that there's no need to explicitly install a JDK when you can use the embedded JDK that ships with your Android Studio installation

Comment: There is no Gradle JDK option there. Android Studio 2021-2

Comment: I did it with the Embedded JDK as mention in the first comment. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69064786/2597775. Also check your Gradle and AGP version. Mines are 8.0 and 8.0.2 respectively

Answer (score 7):

In my case I downloaded gradle JDK version corretto-17 Amazon, and changed Gradle JDK version to corretto and it worked.

Not worked others(ex: jbr-17, embedded JDK Jetbrains 17 and etc.)

Answer (score 3):

If you're migrating from React Native 0.72 to 0.73, you'll need to update Java from version 17 to 21.
Download Java 21 and after installing it, open the environment variables and update `JAVA_HOME` to the path, typically located in `C:/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk-{your version}`.

Next, open Android Studio (I am using the latest version, Hedgehog). Follow these steps:

- Go to `File` -> `Project Structure`.
- In the mid-left section, you'll find a `+` icon. Click on it.
- Select `Download SDK` and choose the compatible SDK version. You might get it by default else find compatible version and download after it finishes downloading.
- Click `Apply` -> `OK`.
- Then, open the terminal -> `cd android` -> Execute `./gradlew --version`.
  It might start downloading compatible gradle version if not you'll see gradle version check if the gradle version is compatible to java version you downloaded then
  -> `./gradlew clean` if the build is successful, you are ready to run app else if same error persists, run `./gradlew --stop` run this twice -> `rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/*` -> and try `./gradlew clean` again.

Answer (score -1):

[Windows] After all you need to clear the .gradle folder from C:\Users\Admin folder for Windows Machine. You wont see there is change in JDK version even you do delete the .gradle folder inside your project directory.

Comment: This is the same as Step 4 in the accepted answer. Can you update your answer to contribute something new?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).