# can someone tell me how do i fix the issue I'm facing in my flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, build.gradle, flutter-build

[This is the problem I'm facing while building or running on android.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Uju.jpg)

It should run and build the app but I'm getting errors. The same problem is occurring with new projects.
My Gradle version is 7.5
My Kotlin Version is 1.19.10
My Flutter SDK version is 3.13.5

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66376361/an-exception-occurred-applying-plugin-request-id-com-android-application-wh

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)? Please edit your question to include the text